# Tree Optimization, Combinatorics, algorithm

Tags: algorithms, trees, combinatorics, program-optimization

My Partners and me, we are trying to optimize frequency process...

I used Java to show our Problem, but the question is about algorithm **NOT** about Java implementation. *Although implementations in java help us a lot*.

What we want to simplify our problem as much as possible in a `JTree`.

[image]

As you can see, each `node` or `leaf` has a `numResampleOperations` involved per node/leaf.

```
L -> Increment or multiplication
M -> Decrement or division
```

How do we calculate the values?

```
Target = Source*L/M
numResampleOperations = filterSize * Source * Integer.max(L, M);
```

We want to obtain only one value per frequency indicated in one `String`, removing not needed branch of `Tree`. `210, 200, 180, 160 and 150` like is shown in the image.

For this example we used only 5 ordered `Target` frequencies (only integers value are allowed), but can grow until 50 frequency values.

The `Tree` must preserve at least **one per included** `Target` frequency of 150Hz, at least one of 160Hz, .., 210Hz.

The highest priority is to have the minimum sum involved of `numResampleOperations`

**How do we remove not needed branches (`those whose sum is very high`), nodes or leafs, with the guarantee of having at least one (frequency required on String), but the sum of all `numResampleOperations` is minimum?**

What do you suggest to us?

We starting with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095738/generate-list-with-combination-of-subset-of-list-java
But due to the dimensions the solution is not viable.

Comment: I'm not sure your question is really on-topic here. It'd help understanding if you recast it based on standard CS terminology instead of Java-specific JTree, JTextField, etc.

Comment: @dkaeae I edited my question avoiding to use Java components, I don't know CS terminology, where I can read about this?

Comment: AIUI you have a tree where each vertex has some independent parameters, some dependent parameters, and a cost. The cost of the tree is the sum of the cost of the vertices, and you want to minimise it. But it's not clear to me (1) what the parameters of the root are, and whether they can be changed; (2) whether `filterSize` is a dependent or independent parameter.